# How to execute ruby script on some event?

Tags: ruby, events, shoes

I want to execute another ruby script from my Shoes app. I try

```
button "..." do
  `ruby -rubygems /Users/kemiisto/Desktop/Ruby/gears.rb`  
end
```

but nothing happens. In the case of other commands, for example

```
button "..." do
  `open /Applications/TextEdit.app/`  
end
```

all works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like it should work. What is the question?

`command` gives you the output; system('command') gives you the exit code.

Comment: 2 Martin Carpenter - no error messages.
2 jleedev - the question is how to start 3d party application.

Comment: @kemiisto: You can (and should) edit your own question. So others can see the additional info right away.

Answer (score 2):

Things are happening, you're just not doing anything with the text that your commands are returning. When you run a system command via 'system' or backticks each command returns whatever the command dumped to STDOUT.

```
Shoes.app do
  @s = stack {}

  button "go!" do
    @out = `ls -al`
    @s.clear { para @out }
  end
end
```

Comment: My script does not return any text. It is simple OpenGl Demo script.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe strange way. But I think works.
Maybe you use Mac ?(from your path),This code works in windows.
If on Mac, I think you can send command to terminal after execute terminal.
or execute applescript from ruby.

Hope this below idea help you(for win).

```
require 'win32ole'

...some code...

button "..." do
  @auto = WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
  @auto.Run('cmd.exe','',@SW_MAXIMIZE)
  @auto.WinActivate("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
  @auto.ControlSend("[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]", "", "", 'ruby -rubygems /Users/kemiisto/Desktop/Ruby/gears.rb')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try running

```
    Shoes.app do
        @s = stack {}
        button "debug" { @s.clear { para `which ruby` } }
    end
```

so you can see which invocation of ruby it's calling, and work from there

Even better, if `open` is working, try changing your invocation of `ruby` to `/usr/bin/env ruby`.

Comment: At first I thought that the usage of full path is solution. I try /usr/local/bin/ruby instead of ruby. It works from terminal as before, but not from Shoes app. (((

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple **require**?
It definitely works, but I can think of nothing to trace back what's really going on after (apart from the **true**, returned by **require** if everything is alright)... Although **system** wouldn't be much more informative in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
load
```

may work better than

```
require
```

for you here.  Require will only load something once.